# project problems resources could not be found

Tags: spring-boot

intento crear un proyecto spring Boot en [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans).
el error que me muesta es

> project problems resources could not be found.

ya intente resolver y nada

Comment: agrega la estructura de tu proyecto y tu archivo de configuracion para ayudarte a depurar

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: cree un proyecto spring boot en netbeas al compilar me sale este error "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project trabajofinal: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
"